# Interface Builder Simulated User Interface Elements misguiding on Landscape

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, interface-builder, orientation

Has anyone noticed that on the iPhone when the device goes to landscape orientation the top navigation bar gets redrawned smaller?

And that the Interface Builder Simulated User Interface Elements doesn't seem to know this and keeps the same navigation bar height in both portrait and landscape modes. This is annoying as the final position of the UI elements gets different in the IB and when running.

Is it possible to add a "custom" Simulated User Interface Element? (like a Landscape Navigation Bar exactly like the original but thinner)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you haven' t set the stretching property accordingly for the navigation bar. Think it is the third or fourth tab in the property inspector. By default their vertical height stays same .. you need to change that height property.

Comment: 1st thats for the UI element Navigation Bar. I'm talking about the Simulated UI elements. You cant set any size/struts on the simulated UI elements. and if you are obtaining a NavBar via coding it's not very efficient to add another one in IB just for arranging the layout (that's why simulated UI is there). 2nd even in the "normal" nav bar UI interface you can't set the auto resize for the height, (only for the width).